# How to define a define in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a `#define` that defines a `#define`?

For example:

```
#define FID_STRS(x) #x
#define FID_STRE(x) FID_STRS(x)
#define FID_DECL(n, v) static int FIDN_##n = v;static const char *FIDS_##n = FID_STRE(v)
```

But instead:

```
#define FID_DECL2(n, v) #define FIDN_##n v \
                               FIDS_##n FID_STRE(v)
```

`FID_DECL` works fine but creates two static variables. Is it possible to make `FID_DECL2` work and having define two defines?

Comment: "two static variables"  What is wrong with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136471/multi-pass-c-preprocessor

Comment: @James: Two static variables are fine except that the string definition I want to contact to my string:
FID_DECL(HELLO, 2)
printf("Hello world" FIDS_HELLO) -> "Hello world2"

Comment: You might generate your C code from something else, e.g. use a more powerful preprocessor like `m4` or [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No; preprocessing is performed in a single pass.  If you want or need more advanced behavior, consider using another tool to preprocess the source, like m4.

Further, the `#` in the replacement list (at the beginning of `#define FIDN...` would be parsed as the `#` (stringize) operator:  the operand of this operator must be a named macro parameter, which `define` is not.

Answer (score 0):

No while defining macros u should take care of one thing
that macro should not call itself (reccursively) either directly
or indirectly.

I know two static variables consuming 8 bytes will be expansive for u.

I have solution over it

```
#define FID_STRS2(x) #x
#define FID_STRE(x) FID_STRS2(x)
#define FID_DECL(n, v) static int FIDN_##n = v;static const char *FIDS_##n = FID_STRE(v)
```

Just rename them going reccursive

Comment: The question is if users can _define_ new macros in a macro, not if they can _use_ macros in macros.