# Outputing backslash in a C++ macro

Tags: c++, macros, enums, code-generation

Is it possible in C++ to write a macro, which **AFTER** expansion will output a backslash sign?

Right now I'm using a code:

```
#define SOME_ENUM(XX) \
    XX(FirstValue,) \
    XX(SecondValue,) \
    XX(SomeOtherValue,=50) \
    XX(OneMoreValue,=100) \
```

but I want to write a macro, which will generate the code above, so I want to be able to write:

```
ENUM_BEGIN(name) // it should output: #define SOME_ENUM(XX) \
ENUM(ONE)        // it should output: XX(ONE,) \
//...
```

But I was not able to write a macro like `ENUM_BEGIN`, because it should expand to something with backslash on the end.
Is it possible in C++?

Comment: If you really want to render your code unreadable, there are easier ways than this.

Comment: I don't think the preprocessor will process a preprocessor directive that is the result of a macro. Also, writing that last sentence leads me to believe this may be bad design...

Comment: Jerry I want my code to **be** readible - I'm trying to improove the solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147267/easy-way-to-use-variables-of-enum-types-as-string-in-c .

Comment: Is there any C++ macro expansion that **needs** an unquoted backslash to begin with?

Comment: What functionality are you trying to accomplish? [You cannot define a macro within another macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144042/c-define-a-define). What you are more likely looking for is static polymorphism through templates.

Comment: @danilo2: I didn't really figure the *intent* was to produce an unreadable mess -- but I think that's a nearly inevitable *result* of where you're heading anyway. IOW, it was my idea of a subtle hint that I think what you're doing is more likely to add to the problem than produce a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Relevant to this would be §2.2.1, translation phase 2 described in ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E):

> Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>   form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>   source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. If, as
>   a result, a character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>   universal-character-name is produced, the behavior is undefined. A
>   source file that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line
>   character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded
>   by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall
>   be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to
>   the file.

Basically what will happen is the `\\\n` (where the `\n` is physically in the source, not an escape), will be treated as a `\` character, followed by a line splice. The remaining `\` will most likely result in a syntax error (there may be situations where it is legal, but I don't currently see any), and not treated during subsequent translation phases as a line splice (line splicing occurs in only phase #2).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any documentation for it, but I would've thought that you could just do `\\` and you'll generate a backslash.

However, in my research, I see that may not be the biggest thing you'll have to deal with.  As millsj just commented, you'll have issues outputting the `#` in your ENUM_BEGIN.  See [Escaping a # symbol in a #define macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135822/escaping-a-symbol-in-a-define-macro) .

Comment: The link you posted has got a very important information: "You can't do that. Preprocessor directives are recognized before macro expansion; if the macro expands into something that looks like a preprocessor directive, that directive will not be recognized" So it is not possible. Thank you